Waswas about najasa
Assalamu allaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh. Question: How do I wash off the najasah from my body? Everyone says that it should be washed off, but how exactly? Will it be enough to take a handful of water and pour it on the area and wipe it off? Will this water not spread the najasa?

Alhamdulillah,
As for how to purify impurity (najasah) from the hand or other body parts or from a garment, it is that you first remove the essence of the impurity. Then you pour water over the area of impurity and repeat pouring until it covers and runs over the area of impurity, such that no color, taste or smell of it remains. It is not required to rub, wring or for the water to drip/separate from the body or garment according to the correct view.
In summary, the steps mentioned are:

Remove any remaining solid particles or residue of the impurity.
Pour water over the area affected by the impurity.
Continue pouring water until it fully covers and flows over that area.
Keep pouring until no trace of the impurity's color, taste or smell remains.

It is not obligatory to rub the area with force, wring/squeeze it, or for the water to completely drip off from the body or garment.
The focus is on washing away the impurity by ensuring the affected area is thoroughly covered and rinsed with water until no remnants remain, without necessarily rubbing, wringing or separating the water.
And Allah knows best!

Thanks for the detailed response. But now I have the following question: For example, I have a few drops of urine on my breasts. Can I first wipe them off with a tissue and then pour a mug of water over them? Unfortunately at the moment I don't have the facilities to be able to take a shower at any time in this situation.
